# VB.Net - "Access to the port is denied" on form reload

Tags: .net, vb.net, port

I'm developing a small application for a project which communicates with a microcontroller through a serial port. Anyway, in that application, I need to reload the form at one point using form1_load. I call port.close() and port.dispose() functions before calling form_load.

```
Port.Dispose()
Port.Close()
Form1_Load(sender, New System.EventArgs)
```

But still if I try to access the port after reloading the form, the app crashes with the error "Access to the port is denied". Would anyone tell me how to release the port before form reloading so that the app does not conflict with an already open port? Thanks in advance...

P.S This is part of a functionality that stores any data that is sent when the cable corresponding to the COM port is removed from the PC and sends the saved data after the cable is replugged into the PC. So, do I need to give it any amount of time before I try to access the COM port once the cable is replugged?

Comment: I don't know what type is Port but first call close, then Dispose

Comment: A worker thread needs to exit before the port can be used again, that takes time.  Just don't close the port.  You are not actually reloading a form, you are just running code in the Load event handler again for some reason.  So just open the port in the constructor instead (Sub New) for a simple workaround.

Comment: @Steve. Thanks. Port is of type SerialPort. CLosing first and then disposing didn't work.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the reply. I'll check it. I have added a bit more detail in the OP if it helps.